# Retrieve records by page size

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a big table if I use a normal query it has a timeout exception. So I want to select top 1000 then output it, the next step is to retrieve from 1001 to 2000 and log it and so on.

I am not sure how to add a parameter in my query.

```
int pageNumer = 0;
var query = DBContext.MyTable.Where(c=>c.FacilityID == facilityID)
 .OrderBy(c=>c.FilePath)
 .Skip(pageNumer*1000)
 .Take(1000);

foreach(var x in query)
{
     // Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
}
   // I want pageNumber is incremented until it goes to the bottom of the table.
   // I don't know how many records in the table.
```

Comment: What is not working about what you are doing here? Are you just looking for a second variable of count for the entire table so you can add your paging?

Comment: Basically I am not sure can I add for(int i=o;i<total;i++) { var query =....} or is there other better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I don't see why not - but with out understanding what your business need is, this is hard to comment on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
int pageNumber = 0;
bool hasHitEnd = false;

while (!hasHitEnd)
{
   var query = DBContext.MyTable.Where(c=>c.FacilityID == facilityID)
    .OrderBy(c=>c.FilePath)
    .Skip(pageNumber*1000)
    .Take(1000);

   foreach(var x in query)
   {
        // Do something
   }

   if (query.Count < 1000)
   {
      hasHitEnd = true;
   }

   pageNumber++;
}
```